# Should boiled legumes cool before processing?

Tags: food-processing, legumes

When processing dips, such as hummus or refried beans, is it better to let the boiled chickpeas/beans cool down before processing them in a food processor or is it okay to process them while still hot?

Answer (score 1):

When processing legumes, you're adding oxygen which promotes bacteria growth. If you do that at lower temperatures, risks increase.

Professional cooks have to bring the processed legumes back to a simmer before cooling them rapidly.

So, in your home kitchen, process them while they're still hot.